# Error while installing ejabberd from Source (Something related to GCC & Cygwin)

Tags: windows, gcc, cygwin, ejabberd, windows-server-2019

I'm getting this error when i try to build Ejabbed from source on my Windows Server 2019 system with Cyginx

```
$ make install
C:\cygwin64\home\erl10.2\erts-10.2\bin\escript.exe rebar configure-deps
==> lager (configure-deps)
==> p1_utils (configure-deps)
==> cache_tab (configure-deps)
==> fast_tls (configure-deps)
checking for gcc... **cl.exe**
checking whether the C compiler works... no
configure: error: in `/home/Administrator/ejabberd/deps/fast_tls':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details
ERROR: Command ['configure-deps'] failed!
make: *** [Makefile:111: deps/.built] Error 1
```

Then i found it is something related to the GCC or the environment variable, So i tried installing dependencies one by one and i tried to make again...
it was working fine until this

```
     make escript rebar configure-deps
==> lager (configure-deps)
==> p1_utils (configure-deps)
==> cache_tab (configure-deps)
==> fast_tls (configure-deps)
==> stringprep (configure-deps)
==> fast_xml (configure-deps)
==> idna (configure-deps)
==> xmpp (configure-deps)
==> fast_yaml (configure-deps)
==> yconf (configure-deps)
==> jiffy (configure-deps)
WARN:  Missing plugins: [rebar3_hex]
==> p1_oauth2 (configure-deps)
==> pkix (configure-deps)
==> jose (configure-deps)
==> eimp (configure-deps)
==> mqtree (configure-deps)
==> p1_acme (configure-deps)
==> p1_mysql (configure-deps)
==> rel (configure-deps)
==> ejabberd (configure-deps)
escript rebar compile && :> deps/.built
==> goldrush (compile)
==> lager (compile)
==> p1_utils (compile)
==> cache_tab (compile)
Compiling c:/cygwin64/home/Administrator/ejabberd/deps/cache_tab/c_src/ets_cache
.c
'cl.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
ERROR: compile failed while processing c:/cygwin64/home/Administrator/ejabberd/d
eps/cache_tab: rebar_abort
make: *** [Makefile:112: deps/.built] Error 1
```

I know it should be GCC instead of cl.exe , from where do they get the GCC installation path or how come it became cl.exe?

Comment: You need to install the cygwin  gcc and/or g++ packages. Run the cygwin setup app and show the full package list and search for gcc. Selecting it will also install all the dependencies needed to build c (or c++) programs. You may also need to install other packages for libraries used by your target.

Comment: I have already instaled all GCC packages and i could successfully install all dependencies one by one , that time it was taking the right gcc path.. this problem happens only when i try to make the solution using the make command

Comment: The cygwin folders /use/bin and /bin should be at the start of your path. You need to be running this at a bash prompt, not a command window prompt.

Comment: I'm running on cygwin terminal.. Do i have to create an environment variable for /bin directory ?

Comment: No. The default path will have those folders followed by your path folders from Windows. Make sure make is cygwin make. `which make` should be /usr/bin/make That first line after make install looks like a windows path, not a cygwin path. See if there are different makefiles for Windows vs Linux. You want to use the Linux one in cygwin if so.

Comment: C:\cygwin64\home\erl10.2\erts-10.2\bin\escript.exe rebar configure-deps
==> lager (configure-deps)
==> p1_utils (configure-deps)
==> cache_tab (configure-deps)
==> fast_tls (configure-deps)
checking for gcc... cl.exe
checking whether the C compiler works... no
configure: error: in `/home/Administrator/ejabberd/deps/fast_tls':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details
ERROR: Command ['configure-deps'] failed!
make: *** [Makefile:111: deps/.built] Error 1 ... what is the cl.exe here ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207495/discussion-between-sasanth-k-s-and-doug-henderson).